# how to display node page using views

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have used panels to override the node pages(node template). I have created a views block, it has an image field and its output has been rewritten so that it is rendered as a image link. Now, I want to configure the views such that it will display the panels page(node page that has been overridden by panels).

What will be the URL of image link so that it points to node page. And also it has to pass certain arguments to the node page. How to do it?

I am using D7

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backwards-- you don't want to use views to display the panel.  Instead, you want to use panels to display the view.

I will try to explain how this works as simply as I can.  Panels overrides the node page display.  Therefore, the display must be changed in Panels.

You can add your views block to the panels display.  To do this, you can use a Contextual Filter.  The Contextual Filter is the "argument" that views needs to display the content.  Panels will provide this argument (the value for the contextual filter) because it is the one overriding the display.

Explaining how views and panels work in detail is beyond the scope of what I can do here but I will refer you to Node One's excellent free videos on [learning views](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) and [learning page manager/panels](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).