# How to override a node using alias?

Tags: views, 7, hooks, path-aliases

I have created node there path is "`content/book/book-name-alias`".
Where
I have override a node using view page "`content/book/%`"
where 
contextual filter using "Node Id".

When I have request a page using "`book/content/9`" a node will override but same node "`book/content/book-name-alias`" it is not working.

How to override a node using an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path where a node is rendered is at `node/%node`, where `%node` is the nid of the node.
Example : `http://example.com/node/1`, and the path which is displays `book/content/book-name-alias` is an alias of the `node/%node` path.

So, to implement this override the `node/%node` path using either a view page ([how to](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/how-to-display-node-page-using-views)), or a panel page ([how to](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-panels-module-part-2-override-node-view-page)) with the same path.

Comment: didn't work url given by you.